# Is UIBackgroundModes location forbidden if we are using only CLLocationManager didEnterRegion?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

Our app uses `CLLocationManager startMonitoringForRegion` and `didEnterRegion` in order to alert the user when they enter in a particular region. We want this to work both in the foreground and in the background and hence added:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<string>location</string>
```

To our plist file.

However, the app was just rejected with the following reason:

> 2.16 - Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.

Is `UIBackgroundModes location` not required if we simply want region monitoring in the background?

Also, is it actually strictly **forbidden** to include `UIBackgroundModes location` in the plist if we are only using `didEnterRegion`?

EDIT: according to [UIBackgroundModes location and significant location changes with region monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511340/uibackgroundmodes-location-and-significant-location-changes-with-region-monitori) `UIBackgroundModes location` isn't required when only using `didEnterRegion`. We'll take out the key, but wow, if that's the reason, what an absolutely crappy way to get rejected -- we wanted background location monitoring so we put what we thought was the permissions for background location monitoring!

Comment: Based on the information your provided, it seems unclear. I would request clarification, or at the very least, submit an appeal.

Comment: (Plenty of apps do what it looks like you're doing, such as FourSquare.)

Comment: Yes, good point. It might have been the reviewer overlooking the feature.